# search Slack messages as a bot

Tags: slack-api

I have a Slack App ([source code](https://github.com/18F/tts-tech-portfolio/tree/923d944a4f2c82a8c7f247d541616d98305f5115/inspector)) where I want to send reminders to channels where a certain piece of text has been mentioned the most on a schedule. It works, but there's a limitation:

The [`search.messsages`](https://api.slack.com/methods/search.messages) API method only supports `user` tokens. I want this to run in the background, without interaction. Approaches that have come to mind:

- Store my personal user token

  - Con: Would allow others with access to the token to be able to see my private messages
- Create a fake user whose only purpose is that user token

  - Con: Have to pay for that fake user indefinitely, manage shared credentials, etc.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

1. Switch on [distribution](https://api.slack.com/start/distributing) of the Slack app.
2. Have the admin, or an existing user on the Slack channel install the app. During the time of installation, you can ask for permissions with `user` token and `search:read` scope.

Now you can make all the searches using this user's token. You'll need to plan for the scenario where this user is deleted from the Slack workspace, your user token will stop working.

I don't think there is a way to control it from searching for your personal messages. Search functionality is dependent on the user token.

Comment: Right, that's the first option I listed, which is what I was trying to avoid.